# calculate the number of pixel in a row and column

Tags: matlab

I get an image, let say
img=imread('test.jpg')

how can I count all pixel values in each row for a projection on a 1D signal to the right and the pixel values of each column for a projection to the bottom.
does it mean I need to find sum or the pixel in row and column.

what is the statement to sum row pixel and column pixel?

is this statement for sum of row pixel : sum_all = sum(img(:)); if so, what is the statement for sum of column pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check the documentation for the [sum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) function in matlab. The second argument specifies the dimension to sum. if `dimension=1`, then you're summing the rows. If `dimension=2`, then you want to sum the columns.  Therefore, you have the simple code:

```
% Sum the rows
sum_rows = sum(img);
% Alternate form to sum the rows
sum_rows = sum(img, 1);

% sum the columns
sum_cols = sum(img, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice an n-dimensional array using the `img(:,x)` notation. the `:` indicates that you want all of the indexes from that pixel. You could also do `img(a:b,x)` if you want a subset of one row.

Using this method, you can sum one row of an image as `sum(img(:,n))` where `n` is the row you want to sum. Likewise, for columns, it would be `sum(img(n,:))`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following:

img=imread('test4.jpg');
sum_row = sum(img,2);
this gives me the sum for every row,,,
sum_col = sum(img,1);
this gives me the sum for every column,,,

is that correct?

Comment: It looks like you inverted the row and columns. You should test your code with a simple matrix. First create a random matrix if integers "A = randi(10, 3,4)", then test your code to make sure that the behavior of "sum_row" and "sum_col" is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got it correct,
so let say i have 2 values here at the end,
what does it mean by If there are periodic highs or lows?